# Determine total number of aggregate weeks excluding overlap periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, date

I have query which returns thousands of rows, with a number and name, fromdate and today. I need to calculate the total number of aggregate weeks but exclude the overlapping date range. I have not been able to find a way.

As you can see, the 7th row of data is 2018-09-12 and next starting date is 2018-09-08. All of these rows is only for one number, but in other number columns, there are a lot more overlaps but example is the same. I have to exclude these overlaps. e.g. in another example, row one is the whole month of January, and row two is a week from 10 to 17th in it. so this is another example.

I tried to do a self join on the table but could not figure it out.

```
select *
from #RW r1, #RW r2
where r1.number = r2.number and r1.name = r2.name 
and r1.Fromdate < r2.Fromdate and r1.todate > r2.Fromdate 
and r1.number = '887'
```

***NOTE: If daycount = 0 , then that row should be ignored. it was generated based on another condition before I exported.*

| number | name | fromdate | todate | daycount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 887 | DAV | NULL | NULL | 0 |
| 887 | DAV | 30/05/2018 | 05/06/2018 | 6 |
| 887 | DAV | 05/06/2018 | 19/06/2018 | 14 |
| 887 | DAV | 19/06/2018 | 18/07/2018 | 29 |
| 887 | DAV | 18/07/2018 | 15/08/2018 | 28 |
| 887 | DAV | 15/08/2018 | 12/09/2018 | 28 |
| 887 | DAV | 08/09/2018 | 17/10/2018 | 0 |
| 887 | DAV | 17/10/2018 | 07/11/2018 | 0 |
| 887 | DAV | 28/11/2018 | 09/01/2019 | 42 |
| 887 | DAV | 09/01/2019 | 05/02/2019 | 27 |
| 887 | DAV | 06/02/2019 | 29/05/2019 | 112 |
| 887 | DAV | 24/07/2019 | 07/08/2019 | 0 |
| 887 | DAV | 09/08/2019 | 09/08/2019 | 0 |
| 887 | DAV | 10/08/2019 | 10/08/2019 | 0 |
| 887 | DAV | 18/09/2019 | 17/11/2019 | 60 |
| 887 | DAV | 09/12/2019 | 20/01/2020 | 42 |
| 887 | DAV | 20/01/2020 | 17/02/2020 | 28 |
| 887 | DAV | 30/03/2020 | 30/03/2020 | 0 |
| 887 | DAV | 03/11/2021 | 10/11/2021 | 7 |
| 887 | DAV | 11/11/2021 | 14/12/2021 | 33 |
| 887 | DAV | 15/12/2021 | 31/01/2022 | 47 |
| 887 | DAV | 01/02/2022 | 27/02/2022 | 26 |
| 887 | DAV | 28/02/2022 | 02/03/2022 | 2 |
| 887 | DAV | 03/03/2022 | 30/03/2022 | 27 |
| 887 | DAV | 31/03/2022 | 12/04/2022 | 12 |
| 887 | DAV | 13/04/2022 | 27/04/2022 | 14 |
| 887 | DAV | 28/04/2022 | 24/05/2022 | 26 |
| 887 | DAV | 25/05/2022 | 22/06/2022 | 28 |
| 887 | DAV | 23/06/2022 | 20/07/2022 | 27 |
| 887 | DAV | 21/07/2022 | 16/08/2022 | 26 |
| 887 | DAV | 17/08/2022 | 14/09/2022 | 28 |
| 887 | DAV | 15/09/2022 | 09/11/2022 | 55 |
| 887 | DAV | 10/11/2022 | 07/12/2022 | 27 |
| 887 | DAV | 08/12/2022 | 11/01/2023 | 34 |
| 887 | DAV | 12/01/2023 | 05/02/2023 | 24 |
| 887 | DAV | 06/02/2023 | 21/02/2023 | 15 |
| 887 | DAV | 22/02/2023 | 23/03/2023 | 29 |
| 887 | DAV | 24/03/2023 | 08/05/2023 | 45 |
| 887 | DAV | 09/05/2023 | 05/06/2023 | 27 |
| 887 | DAV | 05/06/2023 | 05/07/2023 | 30 |

**Desired output:**
the desired result set would be to have a new result set (with consecutive date ranges) excluding the date overlaps. e.g. in above example, I want to remove the dates from 2018-09-08 until 2018-09-11 as these 4 days are already covered by the row above it. So naturally it should be all rows showing based on chronologica order, with merged fromdate/todate. as you can see, there are gaps between dates and I can't go with Min(fromdate) | Max(todate).

| number | name | fromdate | todate | daycount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 887 | DAV | 30/05/2018 | 29/05/2019 | 364 |
| 887 | DAV | 24/07/2019 | 07/08/2019 | 14 |
| 887 | DAV | 09/08/2019 | 10/08/2019 | 1 |
| 887 | DAV | 18/09/2019 | 17/11/2019 | 60 |
| 887 | DAV | 09/12/2019 | 17/02/2020 | 70 |
| 887 | DAV | 30/03/2020 | 30/03/2020 | 0 |
| 887 | DAV | 03/11/2021 | 02/03/2022 | 119 |
| 887 | DAV | 03/03/2022 | 30/03/2022 | 27 |
| 887 | DAV | 31/03/2022 | 05/07/2023 | 461 |

Thanks in advance for your help,

Comment: And its best practice to use explicit joins, not comma joins.

Comment: @DaleK added text but it does not stick as a table.

Comment: @DaleK  the desired result set would be to have a new result set (with consecutive date ranges) excluding the date overlaps. e.g. in above example, I want to remove the dates from 2018-09-08 until 2018-09-11 as these 4 days are already covered by the row above it. So naturally it should be all rows showing based on chronologica order, with merged fromdate/todate.  as you can see, there are gaps between dates and I can't go with Min(fromdate) | Max(todate).

Comment: @DaleK all done

Comment: Take a look at the search results for [\[sql-server\] combine overlaping date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+combine+overlaping+date+ranges). Many similar questions have been asked before and you may find your answer among them.

Comment: @DaleK  all done.  I have updated the post with desired output

Comment: What happen to `17/10/2018 - 07/11/2018` why is it `daycount = 0`? and it is not overlap with subsequent row `28/11/2018 - 09/01/2019` why does it grouped under `30/05/2018 - 29/05/2019`

Comment: @Squirrel thanks for being observant. added to post:
**NOTE: If daycount = 0 , then that row should be ignored. it was generated based on another condition before I exported.

Comment: Ignoring rows where `daycount = 0`, from `15/08/2018 - 12/09/2018` to `28/11/2018 - 09/01/2019`, there is a gap. Why is it still grouped under `30/05/2018 - 29/05/2019`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution with recursive CTE

```
;WITH cteGeneratedDates AS (
        SELECT
            number,
            [name],
            fromdate,
            todate
        FROM TableName
        WHERE fromdate IS NOT NULL 
            AND daycount > 0 -- comment this out if 0 daycount should be counted

        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            number,
            [name],
            fromdate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, fromdate),
            todate
        FROM cteGeneratedDates
        WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, fromdate) <= todate
),
cteGroupedConsecutiveDates AS (
    SELECT
        number,
        [name],
        fromdate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY number, [name] ORDER BY fromdate) todate
    FROM cteGeneratedDates
    GROUP BY number, [name], fromdate
)
SELECT 
    number,
    [name],
    MIN(fromdate) fromdate,
    MAX(fromdate) todate,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(fromdate), MAX(fromdate))
FROM cteGroupedConsecutiveDates
GROUP BY
    number,
    [name],
    DATEDIFF(DAY, fromdate, todate)
ORDER BY fromdate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 2000)
```

Though there's difference with your expected output because of the following: why do these groups not grouped under 1 row?

- 03/11/2021 - 02/03/2022
- 03/03/2022 - 30/03/2022
- 31/03/2022 - 05/07/2023

In my solution, above ranges would be in the same group.

Also, there are no dates between    07/11/2018 and 28/11/2018, don't you think this group needs to be broken down? 30/05/2018 - 29/05/2019

Comment: Thanks @babymilo , it's got close to what I'm after. but yes. the date ranges are not all used. e.g. we can have gaps between dates.

Comment: Thanks @babymilo for your help. Only point I noticed is that your code does not include the end days. e.g. from 30/5/2018 until 5/6/2018 , there should be 7 days but your query returns 6 days

Comment: @Soben_SPDEV Yes, if the date range is inclusive you can add + 1 next to this code DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(fromdate), MAX(fromdate))